# How to select the front triangles of a stl model or a triangular mesh?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl, direct3d

There is a stl model(triangular mesh). I want to use a adjustable, rectangular shape to make selections. Like below picture.

[image]

But I don't want the triangles on the other side are selected. That's to say only the visible triangles in the rectangular can be selected.

AFAIK, there is a [method](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/) to do this. First render each triangle with a specific and unique color. Then, retrieve the color of the pixels in the select rectangular, and convert those colors back to the original identifier. The triangle own the id is selected. I think this method is workable but inefficient.

So is there any other better method to do this selection? More elegant and efficient one?

Comment: If your triangles have normal vector, you can take it into consideration.

Comment: I'm using the color-based picking in my application and it works quite well. If you want a different solution, that would likely involve a lot of collision testing. It would definitely be a lot more complicated and I doubt it would be more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps ray casting... You will need to create quite a lot of rays (as many rays as there are pixels in the rectangle) and perform ray-triangle hit tests for each triangle in the object. You can use the distance along the ray of the hit in order to determine the visible triangles.

Comment: @vesan hi, can you tell me what's your scenarios? like the number of triangles in your application.

Comment: @wan Looking at it now, my scenario is a little different, as I'm picking from a set of objects, not individual triangles. The objects themselves will have hundreds or thousands of faces. I notice no performance problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

This process is called 'picking' and you will have better luck if you search for that.  Basically the selected rectangle creates an intersection volume with the view frustum.  Primitives outside that intersection volume can be trivially discarded.  Primitives inside the volume need to be tested somehow to see which ones are "visible".  There are various ways to implement picking, of which color-based picking is just one option.

Comment: thanks. I think the key is to decide which triangle is visible like you said. And I afraid the color-based picking is the most accurate method in my case.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the color based picking method.  The fully general technique is to render an id associated with each primitive into some buffer that is one-to-one with the pixels on the screen.  The user clicks the mouse and you lookup the id in that auxiliary buffer to identify which triangle is picked.  If your auxiliary buffer is overwritten every time the Z compare succeeds, then your aux. buffer matches the visibility rendered on the screen.